# How do I get postfix to send and receive emails after server OS update?

Tags: postfix, ubuntu-12.04

I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate. As I've mentioned in other questions, I'm not a server guy by any means.

**Background information:**

I'm currently using an Ubuntu server which was updated to 'precise' with 98 security updates. When logging into the server via Putty the server version displayed is: Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linus 3.2.0-60-generic x86_64)

This update to 'precise' just happened last night. Apache, MySQL, and other various services seem to have been running okay.

**The Problem**

I can no longer send or receive emails. I was receiving emails this morning, once I found out I could no longer send emails I chose to restart postfix. Restarting postfix did not resolve my problem. Now I can not send or receive emails.

Here the result of using tail on the mail.log file: (for privacy/security, I've removed the real email addresses)

```
tail /var/log/mail.log

Apr 17 10:35:01 localhost dkim-filter[3669]: A9A2B940AD7 mode select: signing
Apr 17 10:35:01 localhost postfix/qmgr[3783]: A9A2B940AD7: from=<www-data@mydomain.com>, size=891, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 17 10:35:01 localhost postfix/pickup[3782]: BF2F19407FF: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Apr 17 10:35:01 localhost postfix/cleanup[6139]: BF2F19407FF: message-id=<9B1DE71397745301-alerts@mydomain.com>
Apr 17 10:35:01 localhost dkim-filter[3669]: BF2F19407FF mode select: signing
Apr 17 10:35:01 localhost postfix/virtual[6143]: A9A2B940AD7: to=<r@mydomain.com>, relay=virtual, delay=0.15, delays=0.11/0/0/0.04, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Apr 17 10:35:01 localhost postfix/qmgr[3783]: A9A2B940AD7: removed
Apr 17 10:35:01 localhost postfix/qmgr[3783]: BF2F19407FF: from=<www-data@mydomain.com>, size=886, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 17 10:35:01 localhost postfix/virtual[6143]: BF2F19407FF: to=<r@mydomain.com>, relay=virtual, delay=0.17, delays=0.17/0/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Apr 17 10:35:01 localhost postfix/qmgr[3783]: BF2F19407FF: removed
```

**My Question**

How do I get postfix to send and receive emails after updating the operating system on the server? Am I missing something or perhaps there is a service I need to start that I'm not aware of?

**Edit:**

It appears I can send/receive internally.

Comment: That maillog excerpt shows mail being delivered just fine..

Comment: BTW, what are you using as an LDA, dovecot, courier, something else?

Comment: @NickW Not that I'm aware of, but SpamAssassin is on the server. I don't know if that could be a problem or not.

Comment: Apr 17 10:46:46 localhost postfix/smtp[7761]: B639A9402D7: to=<email@sbcglobal.net>, relay=none, delay=4189, delays=4189/0.02/0/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=sbcglobal.net type=MX: Host not found, try again) - Seem to get this message as well when sending to Yahoo or SBCGlobal.net, also GMail

Comment: That's something else entirely. What is configured in your /etc/resolv.conf ?

Comment: @NickW There does not appear to be anything inside of /etc/resolv.conf other than comments: Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8) - DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN

Comment: No problems, what is configured in the `dns-nameservers` line(s) in `/etc/network/interfaces` file?

Comment: @NickW I have auto lo iface lo inet loopback with auto eth0, auto eth0:0, auto eth0:1, auto eth0:2, auto eth0:3, all with iface inet static, address, netmask, gateway, and at the bottom ethtool -s eth0 speed 10 duplex full autoneg off

Comment: so nothing with dns-nameserver ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13961/discussion-between-nickw-and-ryan)

Comment: @NickW Sure thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the upgrade to 12.0.4 includes a big change in the way that DNS resolvers are set, and the installer probably overwrote `/etc/resolv.conf` without ensuring that there were `dns-nameservers` entries in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

To resolve the issue you just need to add in a line at the bottom of your /etc/network/interfaces` with your (your ISP, or hosting provider, or your organization's) DNS servers, or you could use google's (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4) like this:

`dsn-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4`

Then restart postfix, and any other service with problems.